# What is the meaning of sub-second-level in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, translation

We use the term data acquisition to refer to a process of collecting
and storing raw sub-second-level smartphone measurements for
the purpose of human activity recognition.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider a more commonly used (according to Google ngram) construct:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/submillimeter)
>
> submillimeter:
>
> Adjective: less than a millimeter in size

Google ngram shows a peak in usage from about 1980 onwards, with many examples available from geology, radio waves, medicine and other fields.

The prefix *sub-* defines the phenomenon as having a length scale less than a millimeter. The spacing of tracks on a printed circuit board is often sub-millimeter; the larger spacing of lanes on a highway is not.

Similarly, with **subsecond** or **sub-second**, Google ngram reveals a peak in usage from about 1970 onwards, with many examples available from medicine, electronics, astronomy, electronics and others fields. In all cases the term refers to phenomena that happen on a time scale short than a second. The fast beat of a bee's wing is a subsecond phenomenon; the slow flap of a South American condor is not.

In your example, the many operations required during the operation of a smart phone happen in very much smaller periods than a second; the collection and storing way of these data has to be similarly fast (subsecond) or most would be lost.

The tagging of *sub-second* with *-level* adds little to the meaning.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/level)
>
> level: a position in a scale or rank (as of achievement, significance, or value)

The quotation thus implies that *sub-second-level* is a term to be understood in the context of a scale of time. You might imagine it as a scale that goes through millenia, centuries, years, days, hours, seconds. In the case of phone interrogation, the process is sub-second, and thus may extend to even small times such as milliseconds, nanoseconds and so forth.